# R, sqldf and avg for ratio average

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

Why do the two commands yield different results when using `sqldf` in R?

```
sqldf('select species,
    avg([Petal.Width]/[Petal.Length]) 
    as petalratio from iris group by species')

sqldf('select species,
    ([Petal.Width]/[Petal.Length]) 
    as petalratio from iris group by species')
```

Being that the goal is to find the average of the ratios for each of the 3 species.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select species,
avg([Petal.Width]/[Petal.Length]) as petalratio 
from iris
group by species
```

This query outputs the average per species as you are using an aggregate function `avg`.

```
select species,
([Petal.Width]/[Petal.Length]) as petalratio 
from iris
group by species
```

This query randomly outputs one row per species as you aren't using an aggregate function. This isn't allowed in most databases, but allowed in SQLite, which is the default database [`sqldf`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/README.html) uses.

You should use the first query with `avg` as that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's a wonder that bottom query doesn't fail. Unreliable results. Other RDBMS would catch that. But of course, MySQL allows `only_full_group_by` off and new users are introduced to SQL the wrong way!

Comment: In SQLite the second query outputs the ratio of Petal.Width/Petal.Length for the last row of each Species.

Comment: Both of these comments were very helpful, particularly @G.Grothendieck!